LWR Cache problem
I am trying to migrate an Aura site to LWR and I am facing some issues, using the same LWC component, in different pages of the same site.
Let me break it down:

LWR Site (lwc layout)
has two pages (lwc layout)
each page has the same LWC component
this component has a targetConfig property
this property of the component should have different values on each page
but one value overrides the other, even without publishing the site.
when I chose a value on the LWC on the first page and after I change to the second page in the builder, the value of the component on the first page passes in the component on the second page and the opposite.
Please note that the same architecture worked fine to the old Aura site. We are just trying to migrate to the LWR framework.

The same component should be reused in different pages of the same site, without overriding the value of the components property, from one page to another.
Please help :)

Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read How to Ask and take the tour. Including a Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example would be helpful.
